# How to solve the file upload error while upload the product image in Akeneo

Tags: php, nginx, akeneo, pim

I have installed Akeneo CE 5.0.9 version and setting up a fresh PIM database using Nginx FPM server.
Getting the following error while upload the product base image.
Followed this [docs](https://docs.akeneo.com/1.5/troubleshooting/common_issues/index.html#i-have-an-error-when-i-upload-large-files) to adjusted PHP and Nginx settings but still getting the following error.

[image]

Here is the console error where media directory getting 403 forbidden error. Is there any specific configuration or setting to adjust in the Nginx or PHP to overcome this error?

[image]

I am new to Akeneo. Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's might be folder permission issue. Please check your file_storage folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is a misconfigured Nginx config file. The POST request to `/media` is not handled by PHP, and Nginx returns a 403 error. The following code should work.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Hi! 

I'm having the same problem as the OP. My Nginx conf's location block has exactly the content of your solution above, but that does not change the problem. 

Any further ideas with this?